# Rock, Paper, Scissors game, how to implement "Best out of 3"

Tags: java

I've here a class representing a Rock, Paper, Scissors game.

```
public class RockPaperScissors{
    private String player1;
    private int player2;
    private String winner;

    public RockPaperScissors(){
        player1 = new String();
        player2 = (int)(Math.random()*3)+1;
        winner = new String();
    }

    public void setPlayer1(String player1){
        this.player1 = player1;
    }

    public void compute(){
        if(player1.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")){
            if(player2 == 1){
                winner = "draw";
            }
            else if(player2 == 2){
                winner = "Player 2";
            }
            else{
                winner = "Player 1";
            }
        }
        else if(player1.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")){
            if(player2 == 1){
                winner = "Player 1";
            }
            else if(player2 == 2){
                winner = "Draw";
            }
            else{
                winner = "Player 2";
            }
        }
        else if(player1.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")){
            if(player2 == 1){
                winner = "Player 2";
            }
            else if(player2 == 2){
                winner = "Player 1";
            }
            else{
                winner = "Draw";
            }
        }
        else{
            winner = "Sorry, you have enered an invalid option.";
        }
    }

    public String getWinner(){
        return winner;
    }

    public int getPlayer2(){
            return player2;
    }
}
```

I need to modify the code to track how many games the user has won and how many games the computer has won and output who won the most games after 3 games have been played. So far, I've done the part who has won, but I can't figure out how to count the wins for each and do the "best out of 3 games". How can I implement this?

Comment: That's not Javascript.

Comment: `please don't be cruel to me`

.. you gon' have a bad time

Comment: which is javascript version you are using ? Seems like an exceptional one :p

Comment: Do you have absolutely no idea? I'm sure you can think of something, even if it looks bad. We could help you to improve your solution. You're asking to do your work here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for your solution.

- Keep track of the wins for both players and check how many they have won after each game.
- Make a `List` of your games.
- Make a `List` of your Winners.

You might be thinking too difficult. Why not create an `int totalGames = 0`, `int player1Wins = 0` and `int player2Wins = 0` and increase them after every game?